# Save a PDF of a webpage that requires login

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests, browser-automation, pdfkit

```
import requests
import pdfkit

# start a session
s = requests.Session()
data = {'username': 'name', 'password': 'pass'}

# POST request with cookies
s.post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php', data= data)
url = 'https://www.facebook.com'

# navigate to page with cookies set
options = {'cookie': s.cookies.items(), 'javascript-delay': 1000}
pdfkit.from_url(url, 'file.pdf', options= options)
```

I'm trying to automate the process of saving a login-protected webpage as a PDF by setting the cookies and navigating to the page using requests. Is there a better way to tackle this/something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao for the Facebook example, it creates a pdf of the login screen. It should be showing my news feed, though, after the cookies are set, right?

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: portal may send not only `username` and `password` but also hidden values - and it can use different names then `username` and `password`. It can send this to different url then `login.php`. It can also check headers like `User-Agent` (etc.) to block all bots/scripts which could try to hack portal and steal data. You can use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see request send from browser to server and see all cookies, form fields, headers, etc.

Comment: sometimes it is easier to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser and login on page. As I remeber `Selenium` can also create screenshot.

Comment: @furas there was no error message, I would've posted otherwise. Thanks for the help, though. I'll try it out to see how it works!

Answer (score 1):

Portal sends login and password with different names and also sends hidden values which can change in every request. It sends to different url than `login.php` and it can check headers to block bots/scripts.

It can be easier with [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which control browser and you can take picture or get HTML to generate PDF.

```
import selenium.webdriver
import pdfkit
#import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/login.php')
#time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('your_login')
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('your_password')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
#time.sleep(2)

driver.save_screenshot('output.png') # only visible part

#print(driver.page_source)

pdfkit.from_string(driver.page_source, 'file.pdf')
```

Maybe using driver "PhantomJS" or module `PIL/pillow` you could get full page as screenshot.
See [generate-full-page-screenshot-in-chrome](http://seleniumpythonqa.blogspot.com/2015/08/generate-full-page-screenshot-in-chrome.html)

Answer (score 1):

With wkhtmltopdf, you can do something like this from command line:

```
wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar cookies.txt  https://example.com/loginform.html --post 'user_id' 'my_id' --post 'user_pass' 'my_pass --post 'submit_btn' 'submit' throw_away.pdf 
wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar cookies.txt  https://example.com/securepage.html keep_this_one.pdf
```